# How to access the session declared in Session_Start in Global.asax file in another class file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, global-asax, httpcontext

```
##Global.asax file ##
```

This is global.asax file for writing session variable

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Session["myName"] = "something";        
    }
```

The class below is located in a separate library but in the same solution

```
    --------------------------------------------


    ## MyClass.cs ##

    using system.web;
    public class myclass{

        public string my method()
        {
            string x = httpcontext.current.Session["myName"];
            return x;
        }
    }
```

but here the session value is null. I am unable to populate the string.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you need to pass the session value in the method or constructor of that class in which you want to use in the Session_Start method.

Comment: agree with @SainPradeep . your class not going to recognize it with itself. you have to pass its value like sir suggested.

Comment: i better suggest store your session value in object of the type of class